# Burninate request: [group]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request, meta-tags

[group](/questions/tagged/group) is very ambiguous. It can refer to Facebook groups, group statements in SQL/LINQ/etc, a regex group, so on, so forth. I think therefore this has to be a meta tag ([further proven by there being no questions that ONLY contain group, except one that I retagged as it didn't belong there alone](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/112304)). I think therefore it is also a meta-tag, which is a no-no here.

Could we bring in Trogdor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Straight out burninating a tag can leave things kind of hanging and hard to search on. [group](/questions/tagged/group) is definitely useful, the problem is its ambiguity due to multiple platforms using it - the same thing occurred for the [like](/questions/tagged/like) tag.

Potentially a better course of action is to disambiguate it - this means editing the questions to change the tag, for example [group](/questions/tagged/group) on a database or SQL related question becomes [group-by](/questions/tagged/group-by), when used on a facebook related question it becomes [facebook-group](/questions/tagged/facebook-group) the same for LINQ, etc..

Once it has been eliminated then it could be blacklisted (although maybe that could be done straight away, it would mean that any question with that tag that gets edited would also have to have the tag changed before submitting the edit?).

**So....** the suggested retags should be:

- [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) + [group](/questions/tagged/group) → [group-by](/questions/tagged/group-by)
- [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) + [group](/questions/tagged/group) → [group-by](/questions/tagged/group-by)
- [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) + [group](/questions/tagged/group) → [group-by](/questions/tagged/group-by)
- [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) + [group](/questions/tagged/group) → [facebook-group](/questions/tagged/facebook-group)
- [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) + [group](/questions/tagged/group) → [linq-group](/questions/tagged/linq-group) (or is there a better option for this, should this also be [group-by](/questions/tagged/group-by)?)
- [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) + [group](/questions/tagged/group) → [regex-group](/questions/tagged/regex-group)

(additions & suggestions welcome).

Currently there are 1304 questions still tagged with [group](/questions/tagged/group).

Comment: That's what I meant: make separate tags, and then burninate and blacklist.

Comment: @ofstream It's a long tedious process to do manually. A lot of the work could be achieved with 3 or 4 simple SQL updates, but I don't know if there is a process in place to get requests like this vetted and actioned by the devs.

Comment: [tag:group] is "definitely useful"? How so?

Comment: @KyleStrand What I believe they meant was that the fundamental principle of the `group` tag is useful, however, in its current form, it should be split down.

Comment: *Not* `sql-group` please, we already have [tag:group-by] for SQL.

Comment: Thanks @Charles, I've created a table and included your suggestion.

Comment: what is the suggested disambiguation for the regex group tags?

Comment: @RyanGates I'm not sure - maybe `regex-group` or `regex-grouping`? You should edit the question and add it, it's a collaborative effort and there's bound to be more we haven't thought of.