# The [select] tag means too many things

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

[select](/questions/tagged/select)’s excerpt reads:

> Select is a SQL keyword used to query data.
>   'select()' is also a programming function for
>   triggering code based on file handle or other
>   system activity. Not to be confused with the HTML
>   tag `<select>`.

It means too many things. [It can’t even be merged properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select+-sql+-mysql), and there are too many to retag manually.

What should it become? [sql-select](/questions/tagged/sql-select) is a synonym for [sql](/questions/tagged/sql). I can’t think of a better name for the one that probably could be retagged properly so this tag can actually mean one thing: the `select()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll suggest:

- [select](/questions/tagged/select) is merged into [sql](/questions/tagged/sql)
- [select](/questions/tagged/select) + one of [html](/questions/tagged/html), [css](/questions/tagged/css), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) becomes [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) or just nothing
- [select](/questions/tagged/select) now refers to `select()`

That could probably never work.

Comment: [Yeah, no](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select+-sql+-mysql+-postgresql+-html+-javascript+-jquery+-css+-php+-jquery-mobile+-c%23+-asp.net-mvc-4+-database+-twitter-bootstrap+-hibernate+-combobox+-oracle+-sql-server-2008)

Comment: I would have done the second one already if we had a tag filter for merging.

Comment: [Excluding `*sql*` drops it down another 500](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select+-*sql*+-html+-javascript+-jquery+-css+-php+-jquery-mobile+-c%23+-asp.net-mvc-4+-database+-twitter-bootstrap+-hibernate+-combobox+-oracle).

Comment: Why not follow the same disambiguation approach as the [`group` tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179131/146015)? After all it is a key word, you just need to differentiate its usages.

Comment: @slugster: Yes, that’s great. Except [tag:select] has 12,954 questions.

Comment: Heh, if you start manually editing tags now you may catch up and complete it by Christmas time :) Could a reasonable approximation be achieved if the devs run an update script?